# how to optimize contains in oracle sql query

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, contains

I need to use oracle Contains function in a query like this:

```
select *
  from iindustrialcasehistory B
  where CONTAINS(B.ItemTitle, '%t1%') > 0 OR
        CONTAINS(B.ItemTitle, '%t2%') > 0
```

I've defined context index for ItemTitle column, but execution time is about a minute!whereas i need it to be executed in less than a second!
thanks for any execution time reduction guide in advanced!

Comment: do you analyze and optimize your indexes on  a regular basis?

Comment: How many rows exist in the IINDUSTRIALCASEHISTORY table?

Comment: You might try this as `WHERE CONTAINS(B.ItemTitle, 't1 | t2') > 0`.

Comment: I did not analyze defined index, if posible explain how to do it? IINDUSTRIALCASEHISTORY  contains 1 million records for now. using WHERE CONTAINS(B.ItemTitle, 't1 | t2') > 0 have same result

Answer (score 0):

Contains searches for all appearances of substring in a string, that’s why better use instr() instead, because it searches only first occurrence of substring, what's supposed to be faster.

Then you can build index for function Instr(B.ItemTitle,'t1') + Instr(B.ItemTitle,'t1').

And use this function value > 0 in a query after that.
You can see more details about using index with instr function [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/4561119#4561119).